# When to use pthread_exit() and when to use pthread_join() in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am new to pthreads, and I am trying to understand it. I saw some examples like the following.

I could see that the `main()` is blocked by the API `pthread_exit()`, and I have seen examples where the main function is blocked by the API `pthread_join()`. I am not able to understand when to use what?

I am referring to the following site - https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/. I am not able to get the concept of when to use `pthread_join()` and when to use `pthread_exit()`.

Can somebody please explain? Also, a good tutorial link for pthreads will be appreciated.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS     5

void *PrintHello(void *threadid)
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   long t;
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
      if (rc){
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   /* Last thing that main() should do */
   pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Realized one more thing i.e.

```
pthread_cancel(thread);
pthread_join(thread, NULL);
```

Sometimes, you want to cancel the thread while it is executing.
You could do this using pthread_cancel(thread);.
However, remember that you need to enable pthread cancel support.
Also, a clean up code upon cancellation.

```
thread_cleanup_push(my_thread_cleanup_handler, resources);
pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, 0);

static void my_thread_cleanup_handler(void *arg)
{
  // free
  // close, fclose
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

As explained in the openpub documentations,

[`pthread_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) will exit the thread that calls it.

In your case since the main calls it, main *thread* will terminate whereas your spawned threads will continue to execute. This is mostly used in cases where the 
main thread is only required to spawn threads and leave the threads to do their job

[`pthread_join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) 
will suspend execution of the thread that has called it unless the target thread terminates

This is useful in cases when you want to wait for thread/s to terminate before further 
processing in main thread.

Comment: Maybe the implementation changed since you answered this question. According to the site dexterous is referring, by having main() explicitly call pthread_exit() as the last thing it does, main will block and be kept alive to support the threads it created until they are done. That is to say a thread cannot live ouside of the main thread that is main().

Answer (score 17):

`pthread_exit` terminates the calling thread while `pthread_join` suspends execution of calling thread until target threads completes execution.

They are pretty much well explained in detail in the open group documentation:

- [pthread_exit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html)
- [pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html)

Comment: But did you see that in main(), I have called pthread_exit(). This is blocking the termination of main(), and making the thread run, and complete. This way, it is very similar to pthread_join(). Also, pthread_join() blocks the termination of main(), until and unless the thread is executed.

Comment: Do you know any good link to start understanding about pthreads?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, why shouldn't it. This is a welldefined use case.

Answer (score 10):

Both methods ensure that your *process* doesn't end before all of your threads have ended.

The join method has your thread of the `main` function explicitly wait for all threads that are to be "joined".

The `pthread_exit` method terminates your `main` function and thread in a controlled way. `main` has the particularity that ending `main` otherwise would be terminating your whole process including all other threads.

For this to work, you have to be sure that none of your threads is using local variables that are declared inside them `main` function. The advantage of that method is that your `main` doesn't have to know all threads that have been started in your process, e.g because other threads have themselves created new threads that `main` doesn't know anything about.

Comment: Not very clear, are you saying that pthread_exit will block the main() function to terminate so that the other thread works gets a chance and works fine. Can you please point out to me a good link on pthreads ? Looks like, I am missing fundamentals.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI, no it is not blocking the `main` function. The *thread* of the `main` function will be terminated by that. It seems that your are confounding `main` function, its thread of execution and the process that regroups *all* threads. The `main` function is special in two ways: it is the *first* thread of the process that starts, and if it is ended by `return` or `exit` it terminates the whole process. But if you end it by `pthread_exit`, just that thread ends and the others remain.

Answer (score 7):

### The pthread_exit() API

as has been already remarked, is used for the calling thread termination.
After a call to that function a complicating clean up mechanism is started.
When it completes the thread is terminated.
The pthread_exit() API is also called implicitly when a call to the return() routine occurs in a thread created by pthread_create().
Actually, a call to return() and a call to pthread_exit() have the same impact, being called from a thread created by pthread_create().

It is very important to distinguish the initial thread, implicitly created when the main() function starts, and threads created by pthread_create().
A call to the return() routine from the main() function implicitly invokes the exit() system call and the entire process terminates.
No thread clean up mechanism is started.
A call to the pthread_exit() from the main() function causes the clean up mechanism to start and when it finishes its work the initial thread terminates.

What happens to the entire process (and to other threads) when pthread_exit() is called from the main() function depends on the PTHREAD implementation.
For example, on IBM OS/400 implementation the entire process is terminated, including other threads, when pthread_exit() is called from the main() function.
Other systems may behave differently.
On most modern Linux machines a call to pthread_exit() from the initial thread does not terminate the entire process until all threads termination.
**Be careful using pthread_exit() from main(), if you want to write a portable application.**

### The pthread_join() API

is a convenient way to wait for a thread termination.
You may write your own function that waits for a thread termination, perhaps more suitable to your application, instead of using pthread_join().
For example, it can be a function based on waiting on conditional variables.

I would recommend for reading a book of **David R. Butenhof “Programming with POSIX Threads”.**
It explains the discussed topics (and more complicated things) very well (although some implementation details, such as pthread_exit usage in the main function, not always reflected in the book).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any calls to [`pthread_exit(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html) in your particular code.

In general, the `main` thread should *not* call `pthread_exit`, but should often call [`pthread_join(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) to *wait* for some other thread to finish.

In your `PrintHello` function, you don't need to call `pthread_exit` because it is implicit after returning from it.

So your code should rather be:

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadid)  {
  long tid = (long)threadid;
  printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
  return threadid;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   int rc;
   intptr_t t;
   // create all the threads
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
     printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", (long) t);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void *)t);
     if (rc) { fprintf(stderr, "failed to create thread #%ld - %s\n",
                                (long)t, strerror(rc));
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
             };
   }
   pthread_yield(); // useful to give other threads more chance to run
   // join all the threads
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++){
      printf("In main: joining thread #%ld\n", (long) t);
      rc = pthread_join(&threads[t], NULL);
      if (rc) { fprintf(stderr, "failed to join thread #%ld - %s\n",
                                (long)t, strerror(rc));
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_exit()` will terminate the calling thread and exit from that(but resources used by calling thread is not released to operating system if it is not detached from main thread.)

`pthrade_join()` will wait or block the calling thread until target thread is not terminated.
In simple word it will wait for to exit the target thread.

In your code, if you put sleep(or delay) in `PrintHello` function before `pthread_exit()`, then main thread may be exit and terminate full process, Although your `PrintHello` function is not completed it will terminate. If you use `pthrade_join()`  function in main before calling `pthread_exit()` from main it will block main thread and wait to complete your calling thread (`PrintHello`).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.

`POSIX pthread_exit` description from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/pthread_exit.html:

```
After a thread has terminated, the result of access to local (auto) variables of the thread is 
undefined. Thus, references to local variables of the exiting thread should not be used for 
the pthread_exit() value_ptr parameter value.
```

Which seems contrary to the idea that local main() thread variables will remain accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pthread_exit` in the main thread(in place of `pthread_join`), will leave the main thread in defunct(zombie) state. Since not using `pthread_join`, other joinable threads which are terminated will also remain in the zombie state and cause **resource leakage**.

> Failure to join with a thread that is joinable (i.e., one that is
>   not    detached), produces a "zombie thread".  Avoid doing this, since
>   each    zombie thread consumes some system resources, and when enough
>   zombie    threads have accumulated, it will no longer be possible to
>   create new    threads (or processes).

Another point is keeping the main thread in the defunct state, while other threads are running may cause implementation dependent issues in various conditions like if resources are allocated in main thread or variables which are local to the main thread are used in other threads.

Also, all the shared resources are released only when the process exits, it's not saving any resources. So, I think using `pthread_exit` in place of `pthread_join` should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

When pthread_exit() is called, the calling threads stack is no longer addressable as "active" memory for any other thread.   The .data, .text and .bss parts of "static" memory allocations are still available to all other threads.  Thus, if you need to pass some memory value into pthread_exit() for some other pthread_join() caller to see, it needs to be "available" for the thread calling pthread_join() to use.  It should be allocated with malloc()/new, allocated on the pthread_join threads stack, 1) a stack value which the pthread_join caller passed to pthread_create or otherwise made available to the thread calling pthread_exit(), or 2) a static .bss allocated value.

It's vital to understand how memory is managed between a threads stack, and values store in .data/.bss memory sections which are used to store process wide values.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<pthread.h>
  #include<semaphore.h>
 
   sem_t st;
   void *fun_t(void *arg);
   void *fun_t(void *arg)
   {
       printf("Linux\n");
       sem_post(&st);
       //pthread_exit("Bye"); 
       while(1);
       pthread_exit("Bye");
   }
   int main()
   {
       pthread_t pt;
       void *res_t;
       if(pthread_create(&pt,NULL,fun_t,NULL) == -1)
           perror("pthread_create");
       if(sem_init(&st,0,0) != 0)
           perror("sem_init");
       if(sem_wait(&st) != 0)
           perror("sem_wait");
       printf("Sanoundry\n");
       //Try commenting out join here.
       if(pthread_join(pt,&res_t) == -1)
           perror("pthread_join");
       if(sem_destroy(&st) != 0)
           perror("sem_destroy");
       return 0;
   }
```

Copy and paste this code on a gdb. Onlinegdb would work and see for yourself.

Make sure you understand once you have created a thread, the process run along with main together at the same time.

1. Without the join, main thread continue to run and return 0
2. With the join, main thread would be stuck in the while loop because it waits for the thread to be done executing.
3. With the join and delete the commented out pthread_exit, the thread will terminate before running the while loop and main would continue
4. Practical usage of pthread_exit can be used as an if conditions or case statements to ensure 1 version of some code runs before exiting.

```
void *fun_t(void *arg)
   {
       printf("Linux\n");
       sem_post(&st); 
       if(2-1 == 1)  
           pthread_exit("Bye");
       else
       { 
           printf("We have a problem. Computer is bugged");
           pthread_exit("Bye"); //This is redundant since the thread will exit at the end
                                //of scope. But there are instances where you have a bunch
                                //of else if here.
       }
   }
```

I would want to demonstrate how sometimes you would need to have a segment of code running first using semaphore in this example.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

sem_t st;

void* fun_t (void* arg)
{
    printf("I'm thread\n");
    sem_post(&st);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t pt;
    pthread_create(&pt,NULL,fun_t,NULL);
    sem_init(&st,0,0);
    sem_wait(&st);
    printf("before_thread\n");
    pthread_join(pt,NULL);
    printf("After_thread\n");
    
}
```

Noticed how fun_t is being ran after "before thread" The expected output if it is linear from top to bottom would be before thread, I'm thread, after thread. But under this circumstance, we block the main from running any further until the semaphore is released by func_t. The result can be verified with https://www.onlinegdb.com/

Comment: In your example, the thread may call sem_post() before the main thread calls sem_init().

Comment: That was kind of the point to demonstrate semaphore too. sem_init(&st,0,0) would followed by sem_wait(&st) will stopped main from executing any further until sem_post is called. But sem_post will not be called if it is behind in main because it is still in wait.  pt is on the side with main concurrently. While init and wait is happening on the main thread, pt is running sem_post. Now the semaphore is released. You can try it out on a debugger. Comment out the sem_post line, move the sem_post line right behind wait and move it before wait to see the difference

Comment: Anyway, this is not a correct program : we don't use a resource without initializing it. Even if you are lucky as a global variable is initialized to 0 and this is probably what the initialization of sem_init() does, it is definitely not correct to use a resource before initialization and your program does not guarantee that the thread will not call sem_post() before the main thread calls sem_init().