# pthread_join function in c

Tags: c, pthread-join

I have problem with pthread_join(), hope everyone answer.
I am running the program below, and have one row to be printed out. After that, I am trying to delete "pthread_join(th,&val), and no row to be printed out.

I found out all function in program, but i don't understand why.

Can you help me, I am appreciated all answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SMALL_STACK 131072

pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
void* fn(void* arg);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_attr_init(&thread_attr);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&thread_attr, SMALL_STACK);

    pthread_t th;

    pthread_create(&th, &thread_attr, fn, (void*)14);
    void* val;
    pthread_join(th, &val);

    return 0;
}

void* fn(void* arg)
{
    printf("arg = 0x%x\n", (int)arg);
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is what `pthread_join` is meant to do. It has the calling thread wait until the created thread has done its work. If you don't have it, your `main` thread terminates the whole process before your `fn` thread had a chance to print.

If for one reason you want to terminate the `main` thread and keep all other threads of the process running, you'd have to terminate it with `pthread_exit`, not with a `return` statement nor with a call to `exit`.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I still don't understand several point. You said: "If you don't have it, your main thread terminates the whole process before your fn thread had a chance to print.", as your meaning, although don't have pthread_join(), fn() still chance to be invoked (means that have printed line). I don't think so, I think that will never printed when hasn't pthread_join(). Pthread_create() only create, but not execute.
I'm not  native english speaker, wish you sympathize.

Comment: No, you are wrong. `pthread_create` launches the thread, there is no such thing like "creating" a thread without executing it. What would that mean? If you terminate the `main` funtion, that terminates the process and so **all** threads within that same process.

Comment: Pthread_create launches the thread, after that, thread will executing with fn function invoked. But main function terminate early, so thread not yet execute fn function (no printed line).  Pthread_join() wait thread execute done before terminal the main function. I said it right?

Comment: Almost. The thread starts executing `fn`, but in the middle of doing the computations for `printf` the process is terminated. `printf` is a slow function and output needs some time to arrive at your terminal.

Comment: Now, I understand. I have a question . How you know that, I had read many document but don't found that you said? I expect you provide relevant document.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824229/when-to-use-pthread-exit-and-when-to-use-pthread-join-in-linux or https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads