# pthread_exit confusion in for loop

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I tried to create 3 threads to do things and repeat for 2 times, I have expected that all of the threads will exit by using `pthread_exit(NULL)` , but it seems that the output only shows one time and maybe the threads only created one time ...?

I am confused of the usage of `pthread_exit()`.

Is it correct that I can destroy the thread by using this one ...?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sched.h>

#define gettid() syscall(__NR_gettid)

void *f1(void *a)
{
    printf("f1\n");
    return NULL;
}

void *f2(void *a)
{
    printf("f2\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    pthread_t t0,t1,t2; 
    int i ;

    for ( i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
      if (pthread_create(&t0,NULL,&f1,NULL)== -1)
        printf("error 1\n");
      if (pthread_create(&t1,NULL,&f2,NULL)== -1)
        printf("error 2\n");
      if (pthread_create(&t2,NULL,&f1,NULL)== -1)
        printf("error 1\n");

      pthread_join(t0,NULL);
      pthread_join(t1,NULL);
      pthread_join(t2,NULL);

      pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the output only shows one time and maybe the threads only created one time

The code calls `pthread_exit()` after the 1st iteration in `main()`

```
  for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
  {
    ...
    pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
```

so the thread represented by `main()` exits and no further iteration are done, so each call to `pthread_create()` is done once only.

To fix this move the call to `pthread_exit()` *after* the `for`-loop:

```
  for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
  {
    ...
  }

  pthread_exit(NULL);
```

---

> I am confused of the usage of pthread_exit() .
>
> Is it correct that I can destroy the thread by using this one..?

[`pthread_exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) ends *the calling* thread.

The resources allocated to the ended thread are freed depending whether the thread is *detached* or *attached*, the latter is the default.

A thread's resources are freed, for a thread in state ...

- *attached* by calling [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) upon the related pthread-id.
- *detached* upon the thread's termination, so no call to [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) is necessary.

To detach a thread use [`pthread_detach()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_detach.html) on the pthread-id of the thread to be detached.

---

Also please be aware that for recent implementations of the PThread-API all functions return an error code `> 0`.

So you should change

```
  if (pthread_create(&t0, NULL,&f1, NULL)== -1)
    printf("error 1\n");
```

to be

```
  if (0 != pthread_create(&t0, NULL,&f1, NULL))
  {
    printf("error 1\n");
  }
```

or even better

```
  int result;

  ...

  if (0 != (result = pthread_create(&t0, NULL, &f1, NULL)))
  {
    errno = result;
    perror("pthread_create() failed");
  }
```

Comment: so if I put pthread_exit() out of the loop, will there 6 threads (3 threads/loop * 2 times )created in my case? or I still get 3 threads because the second loop will use the  same pthread_t ?

Comment: @KennyYang: `pthread_create()` will be called three times by two iterations, that is six times. The second iteration however will not perform before the three threads created first had been joined, that is ended.

Comment: Is it correct that the second iteration use the same address of the first iteration thread so that the second one will wait until the first one stop..?

Comment: @KennyYang The second iteration only is performed after all three calls to `pthread_join()` returned. `pthread_join()` **blocks** until the thread the pthread-id used ended. Due to this, yes, the second set of three threads will only be created **after** the first set of three threads ended.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to call pthread_exit() where you are calling it, because that will cause your main thread to exit but allow your other threads to continue running.  In this case you wait for all your other threads to finish, then exit your main thread.  Thus your loop never gets to execute a second time.

Comment: That answer is wrong. Sure you may call `pthread_exit` from `main`, and there is even a special rule in place if you do so.

Comment: @JensGustedt Ok maybe it's technically allowed, but why on earth would you want to do that?  Clearly the original poster was not intending to put it in main().

Comment: You do that if your threads themselves create new threads and you have no centralized place that keeps track of all thread IDs. Then you can't join on all threads simply because you don't know them. Think of a dynamically maintained thread pool for example. In such a situation you have to take care that `main`, when it ends, doesn't kill the process and all other threads with it. Using `pthread_exit` is *the* way to do this.

Comment: @JensGustedt Thanks, I didn't know that.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your case since the main calls it, main thread will terminate.

The   `pthread_exit()` exit the thread by which it call. You need to see [when-to-use-pthread-exit ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824229/when-to-use-pthread-exit-and-when-to-use-pthread-join-in-linux).