# Why does thread just die if i dont set 'pthread_join'

Tags: c, multithreading, pthread-join

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t MUTEX = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* func1(void* a){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&MUTEX);
    for(;count < 4;count++){
        
        printf("LOOP 1: %d\n",count);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUTEX);
}

void* func2(void* a){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&MUTEX);
    for(;count < 8;count++){
        printf("LOOP 2: %d\n",count);
        sleep(1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&MUTEX);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t tid[2];
    int a = 1;
    int status;

    if(pthread_create(tid,NULL,func1,(void*)&a))
        printf("func1 error\n");
    
    if(pthread_create(tid+1,NULL,func2,(void*)&a))
        printf("func2 error\n");

    //pthread_join(*tid, (void *) &status); 
    //pthread_join(*(tid+1), (void *) &status); 
}
```

simple code for testing how thread and mutex works.

If I run the code, it just terminates without showing anything (sometimes just one line "LOOP 1: 0")

If I uncomment

```
//pthread_join(*tid, (void *) &status); 
//pthread_join(*(tid+1), (void *) &status);
```

then it works well.

HOW this happens? someone please explain

Comment: Tip: `tid[0]` and `tid[1]` are preferable to `*tid` and `*(tid+1)`.

Comment: The threads are killed when the process exits. If you don't wait for them with `pthread_join()`, the process exits right away.

Comment: my bad :(
thanks for the reply! it really helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use pthread\_exit() and when to use pthread\_join() in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824229/when-to-use-pthread-exit-and-when-to-use-pthread-join-in-linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pthread_join(t,...)` *waits* until the thread `t` is finished. That is to say, the `...join` call does not return until `t` is finished.

So, your question really is about what happens in a C program if the `main()` function returns while threads that were created by `pthread_create(...)` still are running.

The answer (at least, for *some* versions of C)* is that after `main()` returns some value, *v*, the library then calls `exit(v)`. You can look in the man pages or, in the documentation for whatever system you're running on to find out what else `exit(...)` does, but one of the things that it does is, it terminates the entire process, including all of its threads.

---

* I am not 100% certain that *every* version of C and the C standard libraries behave in this way, but it's the behavior that I am accustomed to expect.

Note also that this behavior is *different* from modern C++ where, `std::thread` instances can continue to run even after `main(...)` has returned.